# How to activate a feature (scoped at site collection level) in all web application using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to activate a feature (scoped at site collection level)eg:Publishing Approval workflow  in all  web application. Require the powershell code. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Following is the sample PowerShell code. However, I have not tested it. But this should give you an idea how to do it:

```
#Get all the web applications
$webApplications = Get-SPWebApplication
#Loop through all the web applications
foreach($webApp in $webApplications)
{
    #Loop through all the site collections in a particular web application
    foreach($site in $webApp.Sites)
    {   
        #Activate the feature you want
        Enable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Url $site.url  -Confirm:$false 
    }
}
```

You need to pass the feature Id of Publishing Approval workflow in the above code. One easy way to find the id of a feature is to use [SharePoint Manager](https://spm.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could the following code....its not tested

```
     $thisFarm = SPFarm.Local; 
     $service = thisFarm.Services;     

     foreach ($webApp in $service.WebApplications) 
     { 

        foreach ($siteCollection in $webApp.Sites) 
        {
     $feature = Get-SPFeature PublishingSite 
   Enable-SPFeature -Identity $feature -Url $siteCollection.Url -Confirm:$false
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, will enable feature to all site collections in a web application:

```
 $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://sp2010
```

$webApp | Get-SPSite -limit all | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature -Identity “FeatureName” -Url $_.Url}

Comment: Hi Waqas ,i added the below code in the script file. Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell 
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://cloudx-151-145:12345 
 $webApp | Get-SPSite -limit all | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature -Identity “PublishingApprovalWorkflow” -Url $_.Url}. Am getting error as SP-Webapp,SP-Feature is not recognised cmdlet.